# What is the use of label tag in spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, label

This is my jsp code that Iam using in my Spring Application.

```
<form:label path="username">Enter your user-name</form:label>
            <form:input id="username" name="uName" path="" /><br>
            <form:label path="username">Please enter your password</form:label>
            <form:password id="password" name="password" path="" /><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Can someone please explain me what is the use of label path attribute. What it does Exactly. Because when I cahnge this path value it is throwing me an error while displaying. Can someone please explain me what it is.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Path attribute in Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647050/path-attribute-in-spring)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593988/what-is-the-advantage-of-formlabel-tag-in-spring

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the advantage of form:label tag in Spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593988/what-is-the-advantage-of-formlabel-tag-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

The Path label is used for binding data.

Given that label isn't an input, you can use labels with "for" attribute instead, such as:

```
<label for="inputField"><spring:message code="label.input"/></label>
```