# Very ugly result using bootstrap to align the form's fields

Tags: css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm using spring mvc with bootstrap 3.

I have some forms where I used the grid system of bootstrap, but it doesn't 
work, or at least I don't think is it correct.

I'm using the spring tag library, so this is my code:

```
 <form:create id="fc_cliente" modelAttribute="cliente" path="/cliente" render="${empty dependencies}" customtitle="false">

   <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                <field:input id="c_cliente_email" field="email" mail="true"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                <field:input id="c_cliente_emailFatturazione" field="emailFatturazione" mail="true"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                <field:input id="c_cliente_telefono" field="telefono"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                <field:input id="c_cliente_fax" field="fax" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                <field:input id="c_cliente_codifica" field="codiceIdMacchine" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                <field:checkbox id="c_cliente_invioMail" field="invioMail" />
            </div>
     </div>

</form:form>
```

And the result is:
[image]

I think the fields must be more aligned no?

If yes, what am I wrong?

The form has the `form-horizontal` and for the label I added the `control-label` class.

Comment: Hello @Droide, how are you linking to the Bootstrap Stylesheets? Can you include the header of your HTML file. Also, take a look at your browser console and ensure the stylesheet is not displaying an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `.row` or `.col` classes. Bootstrap has a special treatment for forms.

You need to wrap every input+label with a `.form-group` class, and add `form-control` to inputs, so it should look something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">

  <field:input id="c_cliente_emailFatturazione" class="form-control" field="emailFatturazione" mail="true"/>
</div>
```

see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You could also use html/spring label tag.

References:
[What is the advantage of form:label tag in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593988/what-is-the-advantage-of-formlabel-tag-in-spring)
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

It will render label just above given field.